# Show total search result count

Tags: 8, search

I'm trying to display the number of total search results on my search results page, using the core search module. I've tried manipulating `item-list.html.twig` and `item-list--search-results.html.twig` by displaying `items|count` but when there are more than ten results, `items|count` only captures the number of results on that page.

I'm considering installing Search API and working with views, but that seems like overkill for this one little modification.

Comment: You will need to fetch the total results count from the pager variables. Best place to doing so is a custom implementation of the SearchController. I may provide a short example when I'm back in my office and nobody gave another answer yet.

Comment: Added a less invasive example including theme preprocess hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search queries of Drupal 8 use the [global pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21pager.inc/8.4.x). The total results count is available within its global `$pager_total_items` variable.

So the easiest way of showing the amount of total items is using this variable within a [hook_preprocess_HOOK()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.4.x) of your template in your `*.theme` file.

For example, if you'd like to use the total results count within the `item-list--search-results.html.twig`, `HOOK` needs to be replaced by its theme hook `item_list__search_results`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for item_list__search_results.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_item_list__search_results(array &$variables) {
  // The $pager_total_items variable is a global
  // array keyed by the pager element increments.
  global $pager_total_items;

  // Assuming you have one paged list on your page only,
  // the element's key should be 0.
  $variables['total_items_count'] = isset($pager_total_items[0]) ? $pager_total_items[0] : 0;
}
```

Then you can access this variable like `{{ total_items_count }}` within the template.

Comment: This was perfect! The only thing missing is `&$variables` in the function arguments. With that addition, works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: You're right. Added it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using {{ total_items_count }} varible with twig template not working for me. then I fixed by overriding title of item list itself:

- Go to /code/themes/THEMENAME
- open THEMENAME.theme file and add following Hook

As:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_item_list__search_results(array &$variables) {
  // The $pager_total_items variable is a global
  // array keyed by the pager element increments.
  global $pager_total_items;

  // Assuming you have one paged list on your page only,
  // the element's key should be 0.
  $total_items_count = isset($pager_total_items[0]) ? $pager_total_items[0] : 0;

  $variables['title']= array(
        '#markup' =>$total_items_count .'<span class="search-count-text">results found for the search term “Search”</span>',
    );
}
```

**Please change THEMENAME with you theme name

Comment: It's not good practice to modify Drupal core files. Your modifications will be lost after each Drupal core updates. You are better creating a custom theme which extends the theme you are using, and do your modifications in there. File: /themes/custom/THEMENAME/THEMENAME.info.yml, type: theme, base theme: classy, ... Change THEMENAME for a new name specific for your website